# jQuery Colorbox Dynamic Resize

Tags: jquery, dynamic, resize, colorbox

I using Colorbox for login form. And there's a signup link in the login form. I want to resize colorbox window when sign up page opened.

main page:

```
<a href="/login.php" class="colorbox_login">Click</a> to login.
```

login page:

```
<form method="post" action="">
...
</form>    
<a href="/signup.php">Sign up!</a>
```

Help please ...

Comment: [Solved](http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/fadc3d68ca764de3/d930aad95ebdc8bb?lnk=gst)

Answer (score 1):

The title of this post seems to be asking how to dynamically change the size of the box based on window size. That was what I was looking to do. Here is how I solved that:

```
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();        
    $(window).resize(function(){
        windowHeight = $(window).height();
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        $("a[rel='[slideShowLB]']").colorbox({
                maxHeight: windowHeight,
                maxWidth: windowWidth
        });
    });
    $("a[rel='[slideShowLB]']").colorbox({
            maxHeight: windowHeight,
            maxWidth: windowWidth
    });
```